# How to use "Shopping Product Type" as dimension in Google Analytic Java api

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I can use Shopping Product Type as Dimension on Google Analytics dashboard in browser.

However I have not been able to find this as dimension on Dimensions & Metrics Explorer to use it via java api for analytics,

According to this support document : [AdWords Shopping Campaigns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6109121?hl=en)

Google has mentioned:

> "The shopping dimensions in this report (Shopping Category, Shopping Product Type, Shopping Brand) cannot be used as secondary dimensions in standard reports or at all in custom reports."

Does it mean i cannot use this "`Shopping Product Type`" as dimension via google analytics java api ? If i can use then what is the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions and metrics avliable via the Google Analytics website reports is different then what we have available via the API.

You can check the [Dimensions and metrics: adwords](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords)  these are the ones that have been exposed via the api.

As far as I can see no you cant see the dimensions you are looking for via the api.   You could probably add it as a [feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400%2B) request.